# Trouble forcing ZIP download from PHP web app

Tags: php, zip

This php file is supposed to:

1. receive a piece of information from a form on a different page
2. use this information to create an array of file paths to add to a zip file
3. create a dynamically named zip file using a class that's included.
4. force the download of the newly created zip file

numbers 1-3 are working flawlessly.

The page even forces the download of a zip file that is correctly named and is the right size, but when I try to open it, it says the file is invalid. I've seen similar problems in searches, but I have yet to find a solution.

If i enter the direct URL for the newly created zip into the browser, the file downloads and opens perfectly. As a matter of fact, my temporary fix was creating a dynamic direct link to the files :/

I should probably mention that this is hosted on the go daddy economy plan.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include "gavScripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
require_once 'Zipper.php';


// prepare the file paths to add to the zip file and find the job/client name (for naming the zip folder)
if(isset($_POST['jobName']))
{
    $clientID = $_POST['jobName'];

    $clientSQL = mysql_query("SELECT clientName FROM job_client WHERE clientID = $clientID");

    while($clientRow = mysql_fetch_array($clientSQL))
    {
        $clientName = $clientRow['clientName'];
    }

    $zipSQL = mysql_query("SELECT filePath FROM job_expense WHERE clientID = $clientID");

    While($zipRow = mysql_fetch_array($zipSQL))
    {
        $filePaths[] = $zipRow['filePath'];
    }
}

//create the zip folder and store the requested files
$zipper = new Zipper();
$zipper->add($filePaths);
$zipper->store('invoices/' . $clientName . '_Invoices.zip');

//download the zip
$fileDownload = 'invoices/' . $clientName . '_Invoices.zip';
$fileName = basename($fileDownload);

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName . "");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($fileDownload));

readfile($fileDownload);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have trailing whitespace at the end of your script which is breaking your zip file. Is there a `\r` or `\n` (or both) after the closing `?>`? Try removing the closing `?>` which is optional anyway.

Comment: This did not help. Thank you though!

Comment: I see you have `error_reporting(0);`. Try removing that and re-testing. Maybe there is some error being suppressed that will be revealed. Also, can you confirm on the server size that the dynamically created zip file is valid and can be uncompressed?

Comment: and if you place the direct URL to the file in the browser, it downloads and opens fine. As a matter of fact, my temporary fix was creating a dynamic direct link to the file :/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fileName)).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fileName).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fileName));
header('Connection: close');
readfile($fileName);
exit();
```

Might help.

Comment: Same output. Thank you though